# Magnific popup html page scroll top problem

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I am using [magnific popups](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) on my website. When I clicked the image, it calls another (second) html page in popup and it works perfectly.

My problem is, when the popup opens, I want to scroll the second page to the top with this code:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 0);
```

But it doesn't work. It scrolls the back content to the top.

I want to scroll the second html page to the top which that inside the popup window.

How can I do this?
this is my code in second html:

```
    $('.accordion a').click(function(j) {

          //window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          //document.getElementById(aa).onload = function(){ this.contentWindow.scrollBy(0,0);};
          //window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);
          //this.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,0);

            var dropDown = $(this).closest('li').find('p');

            $(this).closest('.accordion').find('p').not(dropDown).slideUp();

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.accordion').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }

            dropDown.stop(false, true).slideToggle();

            j.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be the way to manage some iframe inside the main page:

```html
document.getElementById("YourInsideItemID").onload = function () { this.contentWindow.scrollBy(0, 0); };
```

Comment: İt doenst work. I use the "this.contentwindow" part of code in another function but it didnt work.

Comment: Note: I want to use a scroll code in second html file. Not in magnific popup main file.

Comment: Could you put your sample code that available to test. Here or on other online service to check the problem better.

Comment: Put the scrollBy code in a setTimeout with for example one second delay and test it.  setTimeout(_=>{ your code}, 1000);

Comment: İt didnt work. All scroll codes effect to the main page. But I want to scroll the second page. The socend page is in type: ajax.